# Custom Wordpress table and API

Tags: wordpress

We're working on a project in Wordpress and will likely need some customization. I see that I can create custom tables, and extend the Wordpress API's using PHP, but I'm wondering if it's possible for the extended API we create to connect to and manipulate the custom tables we create. And if you have any examples regarding this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need custom tables?

I recommend to work with [Custom Post Types](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/) and meta fields with [ACF](http://advancedcustomfields.com/), and of course, you may need custom tables but think twice before going that way.

Now you can extend the [WP RESP API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) adding [new endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) and you can add any logic to those endpoints, query the post tables, query your custom tables, anything you want.